# Search api & solr search => no results found

Tags: search

Configuration: I am using Drupal 7, search api and [search api solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr).

Description & problem: I am trying to use search api and solr search(as a back end) to search for nodes. I have a solr server running in localhost:8983/solr/admin/. I create a solr server inside drupal configuration, then I create a node index using this server and I index the field: title. **The index runs successfully and indexes my 11 articles**.

Then i create a search page using [search_api_page](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_page) to test out the searching functionality. Result: I get "*Your search yielded no results*" when searching for a word in the title of the articles (the word exists in the titles)

I am starting to become desperate here. The index is working correctly but neither through a search page nor through a view can I access the results. It says there are none :O Any ideas?

EDIT: I can query by hand, if i go to localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=spell:test then I get all the articles with the word "test" in their title. Also a ?q= will show all the indexed articles

Comment: try going here `admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings/yourEnvironmentName/bias` and set the weight to each field.

Comment: try to make sure that the title and body fields are not 'ommitted'

Comment: thx for the comment but I can't find the 'here' you are talking about. In any case the title is indexed, shouldn't i be able to see the titles when i search?

Comment: go to Configuration->Apache Solr search->Settings->Bias->Field biases.
The title is indexed but that does not mean it is not omitted if it has no weight.

Comment: i think you are talking about http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr here. I am using http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr plus http://drupal.org/project/search_api. As I can't make my configuration work I'll have to use the native apache solr module you are talking about, it seems

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'solr-devel' module to help http://drupal.org/project/solr_devel.

Make sure that the query works directly in the solr native search page. Isolate the drupal side this way.

Make sure that you have updated schema.xml and solrconfig.xml with the ones that come with the module as per the module README.txt. Reindex.

> Move apache-solr-1.4.1/example/solr/conf/schema.xml and rename it to
>   something like schema.bak. Then move the solr-conf/solr-1.4/schema.xml
>   that comes with this Drupal module to take its place.
>
> Similarly, move apache-solr-1.4.1/example/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml and
>   rename it like solrconfig.bak. Then move the
>   solr-conf/solr-1.4/solrconfig.xml that comes with this module to take
>   its place.

Comment: the schema.xml and the solarconfig.xml are already the correct ones, i updated them again. I am not using the 1.4 but the 3.6 version

Comment: and the query works by hand on the server, but not through Drupal

Answer (score 1):

I've setup Apache Solr successfully a few times, here's a look at my setup, please excuse the squiggles, I've redacted certain parts to keep client anonymity.

I'm going to assume you're using the default Solr config found in the latest Search API Solr module (derivatives of this have always worked for me).

[image]

You should have both a Server and Index setup with Apache Solr like the above, there should be the message "The Solr server could be reached" also like pictured.

[image]

Make sure you have filled all fields out correctly if Drupal is having trouble reaching the Solr server, for example if you choose https, but haven't customised the default Solr config to enable https then it will not work.

[image]

Now it's important to make sure you're indexing at least one field as 'fulltext' otherwise you can't perform any free text searches. It's usually a good idea to have Title indexed as fulltext.

[image]

I don't know how you have your Search API pages configured, but I personally like to do it via views (because views is awesome). Make a view using your Index that you created.

In the newly created view add an exposed filter of type Search: Fulltext.

There's a couple of advantages with using Views so I'd definitely recommend this way over search pages. Let me know how you get on.